# Express returning status 300 on Options

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My express app (for file serving) returns 300 whenever a request method "OPTIONS" is sent to it by my client application. Here's the code:

```
import express from 'express'
import * as middleware from './middleware'
let App = express();

// Logger
App.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.method, req.url)
  next()
})

// Cors
App.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});

// Middleware
// App.use('/', middleware.authenticate)

// Root
App.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Test!')
})

App.listen(3030, () => {
  console.log('It\'s working!')
})
```

In my other client (which is cross-domain also) I get "300" on random:

[image: Chrome console]

[image: Chrome network]

There doesn't seem to be any real pattern to when the "300" error occurs, as you can see.

Here is the code for the request sent by my client:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Store from '../store'

let api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
let media_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3030'

let urls = {
  api: api_url,
  media: media_url,
}

const Request = {
  GET: function(url, server) {
    this.getAuthtoken();
    return axios.get(urls[server || 'api'] + url, this.config)
  },
  getAuthtoken: function() {
    let token = Store.getState().auth.key;
    if (token !== null) {
      this.config.headers['Authorization'] = "Token " + token
    } else {
      delete this.config.headers.Authorization;
    }
  },
  config: {
    headers: {}
  }
}

// The request
Request.GET('/', 'media').then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: What is your client doing? Can you post the code?

Comment: @peteb Yes, see my edit.

Comment: This behaviour doesn't really make sense. AFAICS, Express doesn't send 300 responses unless you explicitly tell it to do so, and the code you're posting doesn't do that.

Comment: @robertklep It's weird. I have no idea why it is doing that.

Comment: Proxy? Malware? Antivirus? Chrome extension?

Comment: @robertklep I am pretty sure I don't have malware. I don't use a proxy or antivirus. I tried it in incognito and it seems to work fine there, but I really don't understand why. It can communicate with other servers just fine outside incognito, but not my express server.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen if it runs okay in incognito mode, I would suspect an extension might be the cause of the problem. Have you tried another browser to see if the issue happens there as well? If not, you could try and find the offending extension by allowing them to run in incognito mode one by one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123075/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Chrome was at fault for this one. None of my extensions was causing the issue, but clearing all data and resetting chrome fixed the issue.